# Fitting Customized Bullets Exactly

Tags: html, css, html-lists

As `ul` doesn't support a list with a dash, I create a class `dash` that deletes `list-style` and inserts an en-dash in front as follows.

```
<style>
ul.dash{list-style:none}
ul.dash>li:before{content:"\2013"}
</style>
```

And I write the following code.

```
<ul><li>This is a sentence.</li></ul>
<ul class="dash"><li>This is a sentence.</li></ul>
<ul style="list-style:circle"><li>This is a sentence.</li></ul>
<ul style="list-style:square"><li>This is a sentence.</li></ul>
```

Here I'd like to exactly align these four lists. All but the second are fine as native. I tried to micromanage the `padding` and `margin` settings but couldn't find the default numbers. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think(best of my knowledge) there is any way to set it perfect align. but here i try to set it with `position:absolute;` you can check below fiddle...

```css
ul.dash{list-style:none;}
ul.dash>li:before{content:"\2013";margin-right: 10px;}
ul {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
li {
    position: absolute;
}
.dash li {
    left: 23px;
}
```

```html
<ul><li>This is a sentence.</li></ul>
<ul class="dash"><li>This is a sentence.</li></ul>
<ul style="list-style:circle"><li>This is a sentence.</li></ul>
<ul style="list-style:square"><li>This is a sentence.</li></ul>
```

and also you can do it by set every bullets in `ul.dash>li:before`.

Thanks!